# a[i] denote number of friends i-th student has. c[j] denote frequency having at least j friends. Show that: ∑a[i]=∑c[j].

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, permutations

Q. A class has 100 students. Let a[i], 1≤i≤100, denote the number of friends the i-th student has in the class. For each 0≤j≤99, let c[j] denote the number of students having at least j friends. Show that
∑a[i] = ∑c[j].   1≤i≤100 and 0≤j≤99

My attempt:
if we consider a class of 2 students, A and B, such that both are friends of each other. a[1]=1 and a[2]=1. Therefore, ∑a[i]=2, 1≤i≤2.
And, c[0]=2 and c[1]=2. Therefore, ∑c[j]=4, 0≤j≤1
so, ∑a[i] ≠ ∑c[j].
Am I making any mistake in my attempt.
Please help me out.

Comment: Are you sure the question said "at least" ($\geq $) and not "more" (>)?

Comment: Equivalent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values (note the difference in indices to get $\geq $ there)

Comment: The question said "at least" only. Thank you very much for taking concern, but I got my answer through Callus.

Comment: But the question is wrong, then. Callus' answer does not tell you how to prove what you ask (which is wrong), but the corrected version of it (with the difference written above).

Comment: I think you are right Clement... it should be "more" rather than "at least"... even by Callus's method, we are adding 100 extra students..But, if it would have been "more than j friends" we get the equality...
So thank you very much for pointing the error in the question and letting me know the mistake in my attempt..

Comment: You're welcome (as a more extreme example to see the problem, you can also consider the case where everyone has exactly zero friend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it up like a bar graph.  Each point on the $x$-axis represents a specific student, and the $y$-value there is the number of friends that student has.  $a[i]$ is the height of the graph at $i$, ie. how many grid boxes are filled in the $i^{\text{th}}$ column.  $b[j]$ counts the number of bars that are at least $j$ tall, that is, the number of grid boxes filled in the $j^{\text{th}}$ row. Either way, each grid box is counted once, so adding up we get the same number.

Comment: How does that relate to the OP's example that hints the formula as stated is wrong? (Either the statement or the OP's example is wrong, you do not mention either.)

Comment: @ClementC. looks like your comment takes care of that.

Comment: But you need to address it, at the very lest mention your hint applies to the corrected version of the question! Comments are not ansers, and are not meant to stick. Answers are and should be self-contained. Otherwise, reading your answer provides no clue that the statement to be proven is not actually the one written in the question.

Comment: thnk you very much for this unique solution... @Callus